# Compare field value to list of values in Visualforce 'Required' parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, required-field

I'm looking for a way to simplify my 'Required' parameter on my VF page fields.

For example, I want my 'Account' field to be required if one of a half dozen 'Activity' options are selected.

Currently, I have to write out the comparison to *each possible value* within the visualforce parameter itself, eg:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!entry.Account__c}" required="{!(entry.Activity__c == 'option 1' || entry.Activity__c == 'option 2' || ... etc)}" />
```

This is very cumbersome even with evaluating only a single field's options... imagine if it had to be determined from the combined values of multiple fields!

So now I'm wondering: **Is it possible to compare a parameter value to a LIST of values?**

Say in my controller I defined a list of strings of Activity field options. Could I do something SOQL-ish like this?:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!entry.Account__c}" required="{!(entry.Activity__c IN :valueListFromController)}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `Set` whitelist and add a `Boolean` property.

```
static final Set<String> whitelist = new Set<String> { 'option 1', 'option 2', 'etc.' };
public Boolean isAccountRequired { get { return whitelist.contains(entry.Activity__c); } }
```

Then in your markup, simply reference this flag property:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!entry.Account__c}" required="{!isAccountRequired}" />
```

This approach will scale well enough when adding more display logic, either new fields, new whitelists, or both.

If `entry` is an item in a collection, you have a couple options. The most straightforward is to use a wrapper class:

```
public class EntryWrapper
{
    public Boolean isAccountRequired { get; private set; }
    public MyObject__c record { get; private set; }
    public EntryWrapper(MyObject__c record)
    {
        this.record = record;
        this.isAccountRequired = whitelist.contains(record.Activity__c);
    }
}
```

Then your markup would change along the lines of:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
    <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.record.Account__c}"
        required="{!wrapper.isAccountRequired}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this work if 'entry' is one of several line-item records listed with the page's record (each with its own Account and Activity)? Will the boolean return different values for each entry record? I figure it wont since you cant pass variables through parameter methods.

Comment: @smohyee in that case I would go with a wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the comparison on controller side and display the `required` attribute value based on the outcome.

I have written a small snippet like this where based on the picklist selection inputField can be `mandatory` or `optional`. The `evaluateRequiredValue()` method is making decision for `isRequired` attribute:

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ExcelPageController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputPanel id="vendor2">
            <p><b>Vendor:</b></p>
            <apex:selectList value="{!vendor}" multiselect="False" size="1">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="otherPanel" action="{!evaluateRequiredValue}"/>
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!vendors}"/>
            </apex:selectList><p/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <br/>
        <apex:outputPanel id="otherPanel">                 
             <apex:inputField value="{!opptyObj.LeadSource}" required="{!isRequired}"/>                
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ExcelPageController {
    public String vendor {get; set;}//Vendor Name
    public Boolean isRequired {get;set;}

    public Opportunity opptyObj{get;set;}
    ApexPages.standardController stdController = null;
    public ExcelPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.stdController = controller;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getVendors(){
         System.debug('getVendors');    
         List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
         options.add(new SelectOption('Cisco','Cisco'));
         options.add(new SelectOption('Alcatel','Alcatel'));
         options.add(new SelectOption('Tibco','Tibco'));
         options.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));         
         return options;
    }

    public void evaluateRequiredValue() {       
        if(vendor.equals('Cisco') || vendor.equals('Tibco')) {
            isRequired = true;
        }else {        
            isRequired = false;
        }
    }
 }
```